# Where is the WP_Query instance instantiated (when working with themes)?

Tags: wp-query, loop

This may be a very basic question, but I could not find the answer.
The following documentation http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query
shows the code

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

but when I look at `wp-contents/themese/twentytwelve/index.php`
I see calls to `have_posts()` and `the_post()` inside the loop with
no reference to `$the_query` as though `index.php` was included
from inside a `WP_Query` instance. Can someone please explain
what is happening here?

Thanks.

Comment: If the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)« and/or »[Why is voting important?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

This is because `WP_Query` is user generated when you want to display your recent blog posts, featured posts, posts with a tag, the best place to find them is in shortcodes folder. All other files serve as templates to iterate, filter and show results.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You have to read the documentation thoroughly, for example:

> The second is during [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop). WP_Query provides numerous functions for common tasks within The Loop. To begin with, [`have_posts()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts), which calls `$wp_query->have_posts()`, is called to see if there are any posts to show. If there are, a while loop is begun, using `have_posts()` as the condition. This will iterate around as long as there are posts to show. In each iteration, [`the_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post), which calls `$wp_query->the_post()` is called, setting up internal variables within `$wp_query` and the global `$post` variable (which the Template Tags rely on), as above. These are the functions you should use when writing a theme file that needs a loop. See also [The Loop](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) and [The Loop in Action](http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop_in_Action) for more information.

Section: [WP_Query - Interacting with WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Interacting_with_WP_Query)

And to confirm it look up the [source code of `have_posts()`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0/src/wp-includes/query.php#L748):

```
739 /**
740  * Whether current WordPress query has results to loop over.
741  *
742  * @see WP_Query::have_posts()
743  * @since 1.5.0
744  * @uses $wp_query
745  *
746  * @return bool
747  */
748 function have_posts() {
749         global $wp_query;
750 
751         return $wp_query->have_posts();
752 }
```

Now you can be sure, the main query does work with the `global` variable `$wp_query`.

But you really just have to actually read the documentation and start reading some code, than this wouldn't actually be a question.